# RAZOR - Display the file size on web page

Tags: c#, file, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I've researched this for some time now and still have not found a correct answer. I need to display the file size beside the name of the file in my `.cshtml` file. I need to use **Razor** to achieve this...unless someone has a file method that will work like `.GetExtension(file)` or `.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file)`.

Here is what I keep running into:

[image] [image]

The left picture shows what I want to display... the actual file size on disk. The right picture is what shows on the web page and I'm not even sure what it's displaying, but I'm simply using `@file.Length` as suggested in other posts, inside a foreach loop as shown below.

```
<table class="table table-responsive table-hover table-bordered table-condensed margin-bottom-none">
    <!--############ HEADER SECTION ############-->
    <tr class="bg-blue topRow-no-hover">
        <td class="width-70">
            <b>FORM NAME</b>
        </td>
        <td class="width-15">
            <b>FILE TYPE</b>
        </td>
        <td class="width-15">
            <b>PUBLISHED</b>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <!--############ BODY OF TABLE ############-->
    @foreach(var file in Directory.GetFiles(serverPath)){
        <tr class="pointer">
            <td>
                @Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file)
                <a href="@Href(@path, Path.GetFileName(file))" target="_blank"></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                @getFileType(Path.GetExtension(file))
            </td>
            <td>
                @file.Length
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

I also have the following method to help with the conversions between different file sizes:

```
@getFileSize(file.Length)
public string getFileSize(long source){
    const int byteConversion = 1024;
    double bytes = Convert.ToDouble(source);

    if (bytes >= Math.Pow(byteConversion, 3)) //GB Range
    {
        return string.Concat(Math.Round(bytes / Math.Pow(byteConversion, 3), 2), " GB");
    }
    else if (bytes >= Math.Pow(byteConversion, 2)) //MB Range
    {
        return string.Concat(Math.Round(bytes / Math.Pow(byteConversion, 2), 2), " MB");
    }
    else if (bytes >= byteConversion) //KB Range
    {
        return string.Concat(Math.Round(bytes / byteConversion, 2), " KB");
    }
    else //Bytes
    {
        return string.Concat(bytes, " Bytes");
    }
}
```

However, since none of the file sizes are above 1024, they all get KB appended as shown below in the third image.

[image] [image] [image]

If anyone has any clue as to what is going on here and how I can correct it, please help out. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to use DirectoryInfo and work on the FileInfo objects returned by DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles. Here each FileInfo object has the Length property representing the file size

Comment: Thank you, I'll take a look at your suggestion and reply with results.